# Le verbe « intérioriser »

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes

J'ai une question sur comment je peux utiliser le verbe « intérioriser ».
Essentiellement, j'essaie de trouver un verbe qui a le même sens que le mot anglais « internalize ».

Imaginez cette phrase:

> Teachers impose their beliefs onto their young students causing the students to internalize those beliefs.

J'ai essayé de traduire la phrase ci-dessus:

> Les enseignants imposent leurs opinions sur leurs jeunes étudiants qui puis, l'intériorisent.

Est-ce que ça marche ??

Comment: I wouldn't know exactly how to work it into your sentence so I'll leave that for someone else, but I think "assimiler" could be made to fit better than “intérioriser.” (But then again, I think "share ... with" would be better than "impose ...onto," so take it for what it's worth)

Comment: "puis" ne s'emploie pas ainsi, je corrigerais au moins en "qui ensuite les intériorisent". Quelques alternatives: "les adoptent", "se les approprient", "s'en convainquent", "les assimilent".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je vois au moins trois problèmes de grammaire avec la traduction proposée :

- on impose quelque chose *à* quelqu'un, pas *sur* quelqu'un;
- les étudiants intériorisent *les* opinion*s* => pluriel;
- "puis" ne s'utilise pas de cette manière. Il faut tourner la phrase différemment.

En gardant "intérioriser", cela donne par exemple :

> Les enseignants imposent leurs opinions *à* leurs jeunes étudiants qui *ensuite* *les* intériorisent.
>   Les enseignants imposent leurs opinions *à* leurs jeunes étudiants, ce qui les pousse à *les* intérioriser.
>   Les enseignants imposent leurs opinions *à* leurs jeunes étudiants, ce qui pousse les étudiants à intérioriser ces opinions. *(Si on veut vraiment être précis, je pense que la phrase précédente est claire.)*

Au niveau du sens, "beliefs" a été traduit par "opinion". Je ne suis pas sûr que c'est le choix le plus judicieux, "croyances" me paraît un peu plus proche de l'original ; suivant le contexte "croyance" me paraît plus fort que juste "opinion".
Enfin, "intérioriser" : ce verbe peut avoir le sens de "Rendre plus intérieur, faire sien.", et ici les étudiants font des croyances les leurs. Cela pourrait convenir, mais j'ai l'impression que le verbe est plus souvent utiliser pour dire que quelqu'un ne laisse pas sortir ses émotions. Sinon, on peut aussi tenter "assimiler", ou "s'approprier" (celui que je préfère).

Comment: Merci beaucoup :) ; pourtant, j'ai une question.  À votre avis, vous pensez que le verbe 'assimiler' est plus bon que 'intérioriser' dans ce contexte?  Enfin, juste pour réitérer, le verbe 'intérioriser' est typiquement utiliser dans le contexte d'emotions?  Merci pour ta aide.

Comment: Najib, note que "tourner la phrase **différemment**" serait mieux. Aussi "font des croyances des les leurs", enlève le "des". Sinon il est tout à fait correcte que le verbe *intérioriser* peut être utilisé en français dans le même sens qu'en anglais. Par contre, je pense que *assimiler* est plus proche de l'original que *s'approprier* parce que *s'approprier* veux dire que les étudiants choisissent. Dans l'original les étudiants non pas le choix (*lavage de cerveau...*)

Comment: Merci pour les typos @Alexis.

Comment: @Spartan Oui, à mon avis "assimiler" est plus adapté que "intérioriser", mais je pense que la différence n'est pas très importante.